# python - is this a valid for in loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I want to access the object, i.e. array[i], as well as the interator count, i.

This is what I'm trying:

```
 for i, pinName in allPorts[startIndex:endIndex]:
     #do stuff
```

I get errors further down, just wondering if it's this part of the code.

New to python here. Cheers.

Comment: What is the errors !? And show us your code...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you rather are looking for:

```
for i, pinName in enumerate(allPorts[startIndex:endIndex]):
    ...
```

the `enumerate()` builtin takes any list (tuple, iterable, ...) and yields tuples of (index, item) with index starting at 0.

Answer (score 4):

Consider [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) which returns a tuple with the index value and element:

```
startIndex = 2
endIndex = 4

for i, pinName in enumerate(allPorts[startIndex:endIndex], startIndex):
    print('index = {}  element = {}'.format(i, pinName))
```

yields:

```
index = 2  element = 66
index = 3  element = 99
```

Note the ***starting index value*** specified as 2nd parameter in `enumerate()` otherwise it will always start with index `0` (ignoring your `startIndex`, unless you always want to start with `0`).

Comment: And if you run my original code in the example it won't give the proper functionality?

Comment: @YoungMoney Is your `i` value (iterator count) always going to start with zero?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is what you're thinking of:

```
for i, pinName in enumerate(allPorts[startIndex:endIndex]):
    #do stuff
```

However, I don't think this will do what you expect.  `allPorts[startIndex:endIndex]` will "slice" the list and create a new one, so `allPorts[i]` will still give the wrong index if `startIndex != 0`

If you *need* `i` to be the index in the original `allPorts`, then offhand I think this is what you'll have to do:

```
i = startIndex
while i < endIndex:
   pinName = allPorts[i]
   #do stuff
   i += 1
```

As suggested in the comments, here's a much better way to do it:

```
for i in xrange(startIndex, endIndex):
   pinName = allPorts[i]
   #do stuff
```

Comment: It happens to me all the time :P For me, it's the worst when switching between Ruby and Python :)

Comment: Why not `for i in range(startIndex, endIndex`?

Comment: @madjar 'cause I'm a dolt. =D   I've been using Python less than a year, and for some reason was under the impression `range` and `xrange` only took 1 argument, since that's pretty much the only way I see it used.  And we structure our code here such that `range` isn't necessary anyway.

Comment: Note that `xrange` is not available with with Python v3.x (just uses `range`), just FYI.